# Task with name "classes" not found, even tough I can run it

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to create a gradle plugin. I want it to run **after** all java class-files were created. Therefore, I call `task.dependsOn("classes")`.

During configuration phase, Gradle says `Task with path 'classes' not found in root project.` even tough I can just run the task via `gradlew classes`

How can that be? How can I create the dependency I need?

Comment: I guess you're defining this task in a parent project that doesn't have the Java plugin applied?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes this is true.

Comment: Do you have multiple projects this needs to run against?  Or just one?  You could move it into that one if so?

Comment: No, there are several dozen projects...

Comment: Could you try: `task.dependsOn(getTasksByName('classes', true))`

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:

> Classes from buildSrc are no longer visible to settings scripts
> Previously, the buildSrc project was built before applying the
> project’s settings script and its classes were visible within the
> script. Now, buildSrc is built after the settings script and its
> classes are not visible to it. The buildSrc classes remain visible to
> project build scripts and script plugins.